# Objective-C - Loop played but loop condition is false

Tags: objective-c, crash, for-loop, infinite-loop, conditional-operator

I'm trying to convert a sectionned table into a flat list using this function into didSelectRowAtIndexPath (I have a NSArray that is initialisated with the number of items contained in each section) :

Somewhere... :-)

```
self.sectionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:macroIntNumber(1), macroIntNumber(3), macroIntNumber(12), nil];
```

then into didSelectRowAtIndexPath :

```
 int selectedRow = 0;
 int a = indexPath.section;

 for (int i=0; i<indexPath.section-1; i++) {
  selectedRow += [[self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
 }
 selectedRow += indexPath.row;
```

But... This crashes for indexPath.section = 0 (first section).
Because the loop is played infinitly until crash of the NSArray call... 
Strange !!!

forcing `for (int i=0; i<0-1; i++) {` works

forcing `for (int i=0; i<a-1; i++) {` works

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`section` is an `NSUInteger`, so it's unsigned. Thus, subtracting 1 from 0 on that unsigned integer is taking you to a very large number rather than -1.

It works when using `a`, because you've declared `a` as an `int`. :)

Comment: Noooooo, you're joking ??? But that seems to be the real cause of the effect. Definitly, I've never seen such an awfull developing environment as iphone/Objective-C language. Damned ! But why am I trying to code for the iPhone ??? Perhaps because I have one :-) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unsigned integers are just good ol' C; don't blame Cocoa for that. :)

Comment: You'd have this same problem coding for Windows, for Mac, for Windows Mobile, for Blackberry, for Linux, for BSD, for any other *NIX... about the only one that's immune is Android, and only because it uses Java (which doesn't support unsigned integer primitives.) This is not a flaw in iOS or in Objective-C, but it is something you may need to brush up on.

Comment: I don't blame Unsigned integers. But if you substract 1 from an unisgned int, it should return a signed int. And I was not only talking about this simple problem. I've coded an app in two weeks in Java. It works like a charm. I started to rewrite (really rewrite) the app for the iPhone since a month, and I have problems with many simple things everytime. The app is not half re-written. And I didn't knew anything about Java when I started the previous one for Android. iPhone coding is a hard time consuming.